# How to store and fetch time from Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore I have two atributes that store `startTime` and `endTime` as a `long timeMillis`

Should I store these two atributes as a number field in firestore or as a timestamp field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people use a Timestamp type field to store times.  When fetched, you can convert them to Date object, then use whatever utilities you want  to compare and format the Date objects.  Android has many options built into the platform.

Comment: So in my model class I made two attributes 'private Timestamp starTime' and 'private Timestamp endTime' and in Timepicker I need to set times on these objects how do i do that ?  'workScheduleModel.setStartTimes(hourOfDay + minute);'

Comment: Use the Timestamp class constructor. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp